# What is the definition of deblobbing?

Tags: terminology, definition

I see references to deblobbed software, such as a deblobbed Linux kernel, or Mull, a deblobbed web browser. I scoured the Internet for definitions, but found none.

What is the definition of deblobbing? (If it has multiple definitions, I'm unaware of the fact.)

Comment: I see that someone wanted to close this question for lack of focus, because it focuses on multiple problems. That's all well and good, but I don't know how it's more than one problem. So, please explain, if you like. I attempted to narrow the focus (although it still means the same thing to me), but I don't know how to narrow it further; so, please let me know how, if that's not sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

blobs are binary firmware, not distributed as source.  they are necessary for certain hardware drivers to function, in whole or in part.  As the source is not readily available, there are deblobbed distributions for opensource "purists".

In the firefox context, there are certain non-free portions of firefox code base, namely the branding and some mozilla services integrations.  Those are removed.  This is more about licensing then availability of the code.

Comment: So, a deblobbed blob is non-binary, previously-binary, firmware?

Comment: Or is the blob just deleted, or what?

Comment: Yes.  The binary-form-only blobs or restricted license code is removed.   there may be some patchwork involved to make sure the project still builds, but that work is relatively minor.